# Java, Having trouble declaring a static array that requires width and height, the variables are not set until I'm already in a function

Tags: java, arrays

I have a homework assignment where I need to use a static int[][]. However the sizes needed are read out of a text file using scanner and cannot be passed as arguments. How can I declare a static array inside the method?

Comment: Arrays can't be static; array references can be stored in static fields.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you might separate the declaration and the initialization. Something like

```
static int[][] array = null;
public static void init(int width, int height) {
   array = new int[height][width];
}
```

Comment: You'll need to initialize it to null.

Comment: However when I access the array from other functions they find a null array that isn't the same as the one being used in the method. This doesn't work.

Comment: @wesboyett Make sure you aren't [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the class variable (note that my answer isn't). And, make sure you call `init()` before those other functions. If you're sure you aren't, then edit your question and post that code.

Answer (score 1):

You can run code that operates on static members in a `static` block

```
public class Foo {
    public static int[] bar;
    static {
        // Do your scanner code etc. here
        bar = new int[5];
    }
}
```

Comment: <blink>    public static int[][] values;
static{
            static void readhelper(Scanner input) {
            String width1 = input.next();
            String height1 = input.next();
            prewidth = Integer.parseInt(width1);
            preheight = Integer.parseInt(height1);
            values = new int[prewidth][preheight];
         }
      }
     </blink>    //gives me an error saying the method is an illegal start of an expression. I need to use scanner and inputfile.

Comment: It tells you this, because it's true. You can't declare a function in a static block